# python -c gives name is not defined but works fine when run normally

Tags: python

I ran the following code in python
`print 'A'*(4*16) + "\x0a\x0d\x0a\x0d"`
and got the desired output as I should.

but when I have to run the same thing using `python -c print 'A'*(4*16) + "\x0a\x0d\x0a\x0d"` I get the error `NameError: name 'x0ax0dx0ax0d' is not defined`

Is there an obvious mistake I am making?
Note:- I am using python 2.6 because that's the only version available on the VM and I don't have sudo to install anything.

Comment: You're passing several separate arguments to `-c` there; **a space on the command line separates values/arguments.** You need to wrap the entire thing in quotes, and also be careful how your shell interprets those quotes and/or escape sequences.

Comment: Try: `python -c "print('A'*(4*16) + \"\x0a\x0d\x0a\x0d\")"`

Answer (score 0):

As the user devordem commented `python -c "print('A'*(4*16) + \"\x0a\x0d\x0a\x0d\")"` The following code did work i had tried wrapping everything myself but forgot the \ before "\xoa